# taskhostw.exe keeps playing ir_begin.wav after Win10 update

Tags: windows-10

Since last Win10 update, my Dell Precision 7510 started to play randomly this wav file. It seems the sound file is being played whenever I start a program requiring high disk activity.

[image]

How do I prevent this .wav from being randomly played?

Comment: Does it happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I tried with clean boot (all services and autostart program disabled) and it does happen. I'll try in safe mode and let you know

Comment: In safe mode it won't load Process Monitor's device driver, so there's no way to understand if it happens (no audio either)...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I've been so dumb....
After further investigation, I found out that somehow I had modified the predefined sound scheme: the open application event was triggering the wav file!
Sorry again!

Comment: How to edit that sound scheme back, then?