# Windows 10 playing exclamation sound every time I change folders in Explorer

Tags: windows-10

I just upgraded to W10, and every time I navigate to a new folder in Explorer, the system Exclamation sound plays. I have verified it's the Exclamation event by changing the sound file that plays. Using process monitor, I was able to find that `taskhostw.exe` is causing the sound to be played. It looks like that program is used to load executables from dll files. How can I figure out exactly what is causing this sound, and make it stop - without just disabling the Exclamation sound event completely?

Comment: It sounds like this could be a very similar problem:  http://superuser.com/questions/1131442/taskhostw-exe-keeps-playing-ir-begin-wav-after-win10-update